# dynamically adding files to a carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel

```html
              <div id="carouselExampleBigIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
                <!-- Controls --> 
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleBigIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleBigIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a> </div>
```

I hope you are well.

I'm looking to seek your help in dynamically or automatically adding files to a carousel.

I'm only looking to see if I can dynamically add them without explicitly defining and the array variable m.

the files are https://optiwatchgroup.com/assets/img/blog/1.jpg, https://optiwatchgroup.com/assets/img/blog/2.jpg, https://optiwatchgroup.com/assets/img/blog/3.jpg, etc

And files are added automatically and my hope is that these can be automatically added to the carousel as they are uploaded without explicity adding them to the array below.

This is what I have done so far.

Any help to advise on the best possible way forward will be much appreciated.

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){

    var m = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    
  for(var i=0 ; i< m.length ; i++) {
    $('<div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100" src="https://optiwatchgroup.com/assets/img/blog/'+m[i]+'.jpg"><div class="carousel-caption"></div>   </div>').appendTo('.carousel-inner');
    $('<li data-target="#carouselExampleBigIndicators" data-slide-to="'+i+'"></li>').appendTo('.carousel-indicators')

  }
  $('.carousel-item').first().addClass('active');
  $('.carousel-indicators > li').first().addClass('active');
  $('#carouselExampleBigIndicators').carousel();
});
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Please do advise if you do happen to have a better way of achieving the same result.

Very many thanks for all your help.

Kind Regards

Ken.

Comment: Do you have a example of your html?

Comment: You need some kind of backend or server side (php) solution for that to work.

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your feedback; @ikhvjs please see html code above

Comment: All my files are all on one hosted online server albeit in different folders, if it helps

Comment: How about just add the img in the carousel html? like this example in  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_carousel2&stacked=h

Comment: Thanks very much, @ikhvjs,  I've got hundreds of files in the folder that are dynamically updated everyday so was thinking of an easier way other than a manual upload

Comment: I understand your question now. If you want to do this way, your page need to know some information stored in web service, such as all image file name. Hence, you need to have some backend(web service or api) to communicate with your page and your web server.